# animação na pagina principal

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Inclui uma animação de inicio do meu projeto ( exemplo "sejam bem vindos" ) e logo em seguida ir pra home principal, mas no caso fica os 2 junto... Será que é possível? [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não coloque foto do código, cole ele aqui, usando a marcação para código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luciana pelo que entendi vc quer uma animação do tipo ***Typewriter*** com uma frase antes de entrar no site correto.

Fiz esse modelo apenas com CSS e acho que vai te servir como exemplo

Antes sugiro que vc leia sobre os `@keyframes` do CSS para saber como foi feita a animação. https://tableless.com.br/css3-animation-keyframe/ assim vc vai entender como sincronizar toda a sua animação e ajustar esses valores da forma correta por exemplo `blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(17) 12 backwards;`

Deixei os comentário no código para te ajudar.

A animação vai acontecer e quando terminar vou fazer um "fade" para tirar o fundo preto de sima do site que já vai estar lá, só que escondido abaixo da div.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #f00;
  margin-top: 0;
}
div.imagem {
  background-image: url(http://placecage.com/201/80);
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
}
p.centro {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace;
}
.line {
  position: relative;
  width: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  border-right: 2px solid transparent;
  font-size: 180%;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.anim-typewriter {
  animation: typewriter 5500ms steps(17) 500ms forwards, /* aqui vc controlo o tempo do efeito escrita mais 1 steps(X) para cada caracter  */
  blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(17) 12 backwards; /* aqui vc controlo o tempo da linha mais 1 steps(X) para cada caracter e ela repete 12x500ms = 6000ms */
}
@keyframes typewriter {
0% {
  width: 0px;
}
10% {
  width: 0px;
}
25% {
  width: 270px;
}
75% {
  width: 270px;
}
90% {
  width: 0px;
}
91% {
  width: 0px;
  display: none;
}
}
@keyframes blinkTextCursor {
  from {
    border-right-color: transparent;
  }
  to {
    border-right-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  }
}

div.bg {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  animation: fade 7500ms forwards; /* aqui vc controlo o tempo que a tela preta demora para sumir XXXms */
}
@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 100%;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 100%;
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="centro line anim-typewriter">Sejam bem vindos!</p>
<div class="bg"></div>
<Section>
  <h1>Meu site</h1>
  <div class="imagem"></div>
</Section>
```

Comment: Obrigada!!!! Me ajudou muito Hugo, usei o seu exemplo e editei.

Comment: @LucianaSouza que bom que deu certo! Se a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone `✔` abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da minha resposta :)